# Running code chunk in R-markdown using exam document class

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to run a code chunk under a question level in the exam document class, but I keep receiving errors.  I am assuming this is because it believes the output from the R-code is Latex code.

````
---
output: pdf_document
documentclass: exam
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
---
\begin{questions}
    \question Answer question...
     ```{r}
        iris%>%
           group_by(Species)%>%
           summarize(Total=n())
     ```
    \end{questions}
````

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example. That said, the function `summaries` should perhaps be `summarize`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo, it was correct in the document I was having issues with.  I have added the header from the R-markdown script.  The example uses iris data set.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes `\begin{"some environment") ... \end{"some environment")` doesn't play well with R chuncks. One work around is to define a new environment.

For example, I defined a file preamble.tex with the following information:

**preamble.tex**

```
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\begin{questions}}
\newcommand{\eQ}{\end{questions}}
```

Then, I ran the following.

**exam.Rmd**

````
---
documentclass: exam
geometry: margin=.5in
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    highlight: haddock
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
      before_body: doc-prefix.tex
      after_body: doc-suffix.tex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\bQ

## Including Plots

\question You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\question We can keep the pound signs.

\eQ
````

Here is the resulting output.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q21I.png)

Comment: Is there a different way to manage it if I would like the code chunk to to be under `\begin{parts}`.  When I added a command for this it changed.

Comment: What about solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something working. It needs some libraries and uses `knitr` to create the output.

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
documentclass: exam
header-includes: \usepackage{float}
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
```

\begin{questions}
\question Answer question...
```{r, echo=F, comment=NA}
summary = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(Total=n())
kable(summary, format='latex')
```
\end{questions}
````

The problem seems to be the inclusion of `#` in the output from R for processing by Latex. I avoid this by using `kable`.