# How to show solutions using LaTeX exam class in RMarkdown file?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I want to use the LaTeX `exam` document [class](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf) in RMarkdown files to create class quizzes, but I don't know how to show the answers.

I create a `quiz.Rmd` file for the quiz, which includes a `preamble.tex` file to specify the `questions` environment (following the answer at  [Running code chunk in R-markdown using exam document class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577496/running-code-chunk-in-r-markdown-using-exam-document-class)) and put that `preamble.tex` in the same directory as `quiz.Rmd`.

`quiz.Rmd` contains:

```
---
title: "Quiz 1"
author: "This Author"
date: "2019-09-04"
documentclass: exam
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``

\bQ

\question What is the answer to this question?

\begin{solution}
The answer is "yes".
\end{solution}

\eQ
```

and `preamble.tex` contains

```
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\begin{questions}}
\newcommand{\eQ}{\end{questions}}
```

I successfully knit `quiz.Rmd`, which does not include the solutions:

[image]

I tried adding `\documentclass[answers]{exam}` to the `preamble.tex` and removing it from `quiz.Rmd`, but this produced the error `! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.`

How do I get the solutions to appear, to create a key for grading, for example?

(Note 1: I see [R/exams](http://www.r-exams.org/general/welcome/), but I'm not ready to transition to this yet.)

(Note 2: I removed one backtick in each of the two lines around the `knitr::` line to ease formatting to post this question.)

Comment: can you try `classoption: answers` ?

Comment: @samcarter 's solution works.  I add `classoption: answers` to the `quiz.Rmd` YAML header and knit, and the solutions are properly visible.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by @samcarter works. I add `classoption: answers` to the `quiz.Rmd` YAML header and knit, and the solutions are properly visible, as below.

[image]

The full minimal working example looks like this:

```
---
title: "Quiz 1"
author: "This Author"
date: "2019-09-04"
documentclass: exam
classoption: answers
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``

\bQ

\question What is the answer to this question?

\begin{solution}
The answer is "yes".
\end{solution}

\eQ
```

Further, to add R chunks, per @FedericoMolinaMagne's question, define the `solution` environment in `preamble.tex` as well.  The full `preamble.tex` is

```
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\begin{questions}}
\newcommand{\eQ}{\end{questions}}
\newcommand{\bS}{\begin{solution}}
\newcommand{\eS}{\end{solution}}
```

and the `.Rmd` looks as below, with the exception that I removed one backtick from around the two code chunks to improve the legibility here. One must add those backticks in to compile.

```
---
title: "Quiz"
author: "Me"
date: "2019-09-04"
documentclass: exam
classoption: answers
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``

\bQ

\question What is the answer to this question?

\bS
The answer is "yes".
\eS

\question What is $5+2$?

\bS
``{r}
5 + 2
``
\eS

\eQ
```

Then, the output is as below.

[image: Compiled PDF from above Rmd]

Comment: Can you add R code chunk in solutions properly?

Comment: Yes, @FedericoMolinaMagne. I've added the `solution` environment above as well, and then you can do so.

Comment: I was trying but I forgot to use two backsticks!! Thanks!!

Comment: in order to get your same result I've to used 3 backstick. Are you using 3 or 2?

Comment: @FedericoMolinaMagne, 3. In order to successfully compile, you must use 3 backticks around the code chunks. I show only 2 above just to ease the presentation here.